# Keras combine sequence of input data with static features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently struggeling with the Problem of combining static features with a sequence of input data within a batch.

I have two channels of input data, one is processed via a convolutional neural network (eg. vgg-16 or comparable) and outputs a feature map.

My second input channel contains a list (with variable length) of input data.

Each single entry of that list and the calculated feature map should be fed into a classifier.

I know that I can use a TimeDistributed Wrapper to process sequences of data, but that only partially solves my problem:

- The calculation of the feature map in the first input channel is costly and should only be performed once per batch
- As the list in the second channel has a variable length, I cannot make use of a repeat Layer to to duplicate the feature map properly, additionally I run into memory problems as I cannot hold several hundreds (or thousand) copies of the feature map in gpu memory

What is the best way to properly combine static data (ones per batch) with a sequence of data?